# git --shared permissions reset

Tags: git, permissions

I have a whole bunch of git repositories in `/srv/git` manually administrated (not using [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst)), which I have obviously buggered up the permissions for, since I now get `error: failed to push some refs to` type errors, after some poor `chmod` invocations on the server.

I also mistakenly added +x to all hooks and I need to remove that and add them back manually by hand I suspect.

How does one reset a `/srv/git` directory to default `git init --shared` type permissions on all the repositories contained within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following commands seem to restore some sanity.

```
find /srv/git -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
find /srv/git -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
```

Obviously I need to fix the hooks still.